# django serialize foreign key objects

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-serializer

- [Serialize django model with foreign key models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015229/serialize-django-model-with-foreign-key-models)
- [Serializing Foreign Key objects in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753359/serializing-foreign-key-objects-in-django)
- [get foreign key objects in a single query - Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832997/get-foreign-key-objects-in-a-single-query-django)

There are couple of question asking for the same thing already. But they are from 2010, and it didn't help me so much. So I figure it maybe been some update to this front since 2010?

On google I found this [link](http://mohtasham.info/article/serializing-foreign-key-django-model/), which explain usage of [natural keys](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#natural-keys). However my problem concerns of getting foreign objects from `django.contrib.auth.models.User` so it doesn't help.

My problem is as following. I want to serialize the QuerySet so I get the foreign key objects also, because I want to pass it as JSON to the client. The serializer from `django.core` doesn't do that. So in my case to simply the problem I had added another field to the model to contain the value I need from the foreign object. But it however introduce redundant data.

My example model it contains the `username` which I would like if possible remove, and instead get it by the foreign key.

```
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One potential way around this is to construct your own dictionary object based on the returns of a queryset. You'd do something like this:

```
queryset = Model.objects.all()
list = [] #create list
for row in queryset: #populate list
    list.append({'title':row.title, 'body': row.body, 'name': row.user.username})
recipe_list_json = json.dumps(list) #dump list as JSON
return HttpResponse(recipe_list_json, 'application/javascript')
```

You need to import json for this to work.

```
import json
```

Comment: No problem. Django's serializer definitely seems a little bit limited. You could also try using this: http://code.google.com/p/wadofstuff/wiki/DjangoFullSerializers

Answer (score 1):

You could use Django REST frameworks' [serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers.html#modelserializer).