# JavaScript and Django: How can I access Django subfields?

Tags: javascript, django, datafield

I'm writing a JavaScript function that makes use of Django objects. I have an object, which I'll call `item`, which has a field `user`. So `item.user` should give me an instance of a Django User object.

Now a User object has a number of subfields, including `profile`. In Django, I can access this field with `{{ user.profile }}`. In JavaScript, however, `item.user.profile` is "undefined". Is there a different syntax, or is some other method of getting the data necessary?

Comment: How are you telling Javascript about your Django object?

Comment: You probably have not serialized the foreign key objects. See this post for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507011/django-serialize-foreign-key-objects

Comment: I'm getting `item` with `$.each(json, function(i,item)`. Is this not already serialized? Can I serialize from within JavaScript?