# Select_Related and JSON - How to serialize foreign key objects

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Suppose I have 2 models:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I need to return all entries with corresponding blogs in JSON format:

```
TO_JSON = serializers.serialize('json', Entry.objects.select_related('blog').filter(...))
```

TO_JSON contains all entries I need, but with no blogs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Edit

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related, you can try like this:

```
e = Entry.objects.select_related('blog').filter(...)
return serializers.serialize('json', [x.blog for x in e])
```

Comment: Previous answer was not correct because then e was not iterable hence was not serializable. So I edited it.

Comment: Thank you! Work very well. However, I was not able to return entries, but only blogs. I will post another answer that allowed me to do both.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@bento](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1198166/bento) who suggested the following answer, which is available at [django serialize foreign key objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507011/django-serialize-foreign-key-objects):

```
entries = Entry.objects.select_related('blog').filter(...)
list = []
for row in entries:
        list.append({'blog_title':row.blog.title, 'entry_title': row.title})
return json.dumps(list)
```