# django - key error in serializer with foreign key models

Tags: python, django, serialization

I checked out all related questions but still curious to know if there exist an updated answer .

[django serialize foreign key objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507011/django-serialize-foreign-key-objects)

So , I have a model which has three foreign keys  , next when I am trying to GET a response using that model , they keys in **List** is appended with "_id" - so whenever I am **serializing**  , I am getting the **"KeyError at"** error.

**Error :**

> KeyError at /api/v1/user/skill/upvotes/1 'skill'

**Model :**

```
class UserSkillUpvotes(models.Model):
    unique_together = (('user_skill', 'upvote_by'),)
    skill = models.ForeignKey('Skill',on_delete=models.CASCADE , related_name='all_upvote_for_user_skill')
    upvote_by =  models.ForeignKey('auth.User',on_delete=models.CASCADE , related_name='all_upvote_by_user') 
    upvote_for = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',on_delete=models.CASCADE , related_name='all_upvote_for_user')
```

**Serializer :**

```
class UserSkillUpvotesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=UserSkillUpvotes
        fields='__all__'
```

**View :**
if request.method == 'GET':

```
try:
    user_skill_upvotes = list(UserSkillUpvotes.objects.filter(upvote_for=pk).all().values()) # get all upvotes on skills of the requested user
except (UserSkillUpvotes.DoesNotExist,User.DoesNotExist) as e:
    return HttpResponse(status=404)
serializer = UserSkillUpvotesSerializer(user_skill_upvotes,many=True)
return Response(serializer.data)
```

**Console error -**

```
File "C:\code\django\wantedly\src\wantedly_webapp\views\AllViews.py", line 75, in user_skill_upvotes
  return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my problem by not fetching all values from the Object . 
Learnt the basics of ORM :)

In my views I changed this line from this

```
user_skill_upvotes = list(UserSkillUpvotes.objects.filter(upvote_for=pk).all().values()) # get all upvotes on skills of the requested user
```

to this

```
 user_skill_upvotes = list(UserSkillUpvotes.objects.filter(upvote_for=pk))
```